# wxWidgets and locking resources

Tags: c++, multithreading, locking, wxwidgets

I'm new to wxWidgets (C++), and threads for that matter.  What should I be aware of concerning shared resources?  Should I implement some sort of semaphore-based locking of resources that may be used by both the GUI thread and the worker thread(s)?  Does wxWidgets offer some capability for dealing with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what your choice of threading library is at this point but in your case I'd use wxThread (see [here](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/overview_thread.html) & [here](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_thread.html) for documentation).

> What should I be aware of concerning
>   shared resources?

See the **Important notes for multithreaded applications** part [here](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/overview_thread.html) for wxWidgets specific multi-threading issues.
Other than that the 'usual' concerns about shared resources apply.

> Should I implement some sort of
>   semaphore-based locking of resources
>   that may be used by both the GUI
>   thread and the worker thread(s)? Does
>   wxWidgets offer some capability for
>   dealing with this?

wxWidgets already implements a number of synchronization objects, see [here](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/group__group__class__threading.html).
As a side note prefer using the RAII locker helpers (wxMutexLocker, wxCriticalSectionLocker) instead of explicitly acquiring/releasing.